# How to highlight text in Preview properly?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I know this problem could be trivial, but it just bothers a lot. I can use the highlight function of preview properly before like the following:

[image]

but now when I try to highlight the text again, it just messed up like below

[image]

Is this a bug of preview? Any configuration could solve this problem?

Comment: what kind of file is it?

Comment: @Buscar웃 PDF file

Comment: Did you recently upgrade your OS? What version of OS X are you using? It looks like it's still highlighting but using a "realistic" highlighter instead of just rectangular boxes around the words.

Comment: It also could be due to the way the PDF you are trying to highlight was created. Try this, as this is reported to possibly help: Go to Tools > Rotate Left, then Tools > Rotate Right and try highlighting again.

Comment: @tubedogg I'm using mavericks 10.9.5. I just re-downloaded the  file and now it works fine, but I'll try to use the way you suggested next time I encounter this problem, thanks :D

Comment: @tubedogg unfortunately, I just encountered this problem again and tried your way but without luck.